# Access nested json data in single get?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to trying to get a value out of a json object.  How would I get a third level json object:

json format looks like:

```
feedString = {"level1":[{"level2":{"level3":{"valueIWant":10}}}]}
```

Code is:

```
JSONObject  jsonFeed = new JSONObject(feedString);
jsonFeed.get("level1.level2.level3.valueIWant");
```

Can I get nested levels in one get? What should my key look like?

Comment: com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.json.JSONObject;

Comment: That's the class, I meant the actual library, but I guess that's enough.

Comment: I don't think you can do it like that; you're looking for a solution that's basically a JSON EL language--you could eval with an EL against the parsed JSONObject.

Comment: This seems like a very common use case.  It doesn't make sense that you need to string so many gets together but I guess that's easy enough.

Comment: You could give [this](http://projects.plural.cc/projects/jsonij/wiki/JPath) a shot.

Comment: Make that an answer and I'll accept

Comment: Check out [json-path](http://code.google.com/p/json-path/) too, it uses dot notation, and has a pom if you're running Maven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could give [JSONiJ (JSON in Java)](http://projects.plural.cc/projects/jsonij/wiki/JPath) a shot; it's a Java version of [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) and basically maps (a subset of) XPath syntax onto JSON objects.

Also, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849816/is-there-a-java-implementation-of-jsonpath) for some other ideas; it looks like [json-path](http://code.google.com/p/json-path/) has a Java version, and uses dot notation.

The other option is to build an EL bridge between JSONObjects and something like MVEL or OGNL, which would give you the more-familiar dot notation. (I thought there was an MVEL/JSON bridge, but can't find it now.)

Answer (score 4):

You should use JSONPath. Check out this Java implementation http://code.google.com/p/json-path/

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while now, but I have some good news. Just tried [beanutils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils) and it works like a charm!
Assuming you have the json converted to map: (any parser can do that)

```
private Map<String, Object> json;
```

All you need is:

```
PropertyUtils.getProperty(json, "level1.level2.level3.valueIWant")
```

Have fun :)